# How to force pandoc not to build <a> tag when url is in YAML metadata

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, pandoc

Let's say we have simple empty `.Rmd` file with YAML metadata like this

```
---
link: https://google.com
---
```

Then in `html` template, it will show up automatically in `<a>` tag

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="uri">http://google.com</a>
```

How to force pandoc not to build `<a>` when there is url in YAML? I mean what I wanna finally get is plan text in `html` template

```
http://google.com
```

Or if I use own `html` template I can add a link that way

```
<a href="$link$">Google</a>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by an extension that is enabled by default with the `md_extensions` option under the output format, specifically `auto_link_bare_uris`. You can disable this in your *YAML* header.

```
---
title: https://www.google.com
output:
  html_document:
    md_extensions: -autolink_bare_uris
---
```

Just note that this will affect auto linking of URIs throughout your document, not only in the title. After disabling the extension you will need to enclose links in angle brackets to create links, *i.e.* `<https://www.google.com>`. The *Pandoc* [guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#automatic-links) and the *R Markdown* [site](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#markdown_extensions) contain the detail covering this.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing a character in the title with an HTML ASCII reference will stop the link from auto generating and display on the page correctly.  For example, here I replace the colon:

```
---
title: https&#58;//gooogle.com
---
```

Comment: Actually it's sub-optimal solution.

Comment: Agreed... If there is another one I look forward to learning how to do it.